# Running a shell script from Nodejs

Tags: node.js, shell, child-process, spawn

I have a shell script `start.sh` whose job is to spawn multiple java processes in the background and then exit normally like so:

```
java -jar jar1.jar &
java -jar jar2.jar &
...
exit 0
```

A bunch of output is printed:

```
Starting jar1
Starting jar2
...
```

Now I want nodejs to invoke `start.sh` keep track of the output so I can act on it when `starter.sh` is done

Problem is Nodejs considers `starter.sh` to be done only when all the java processes that have been started are dead.
Which is weird because from a shell, `starter.sh` exits right away and does not have any relations with the java processes anymore

How I can make `starter.sh` behave the same way when invoked from node?

This is the code I use to spawn `starter.sh`:

```
  const process = spawn('starter.sh', []);

  process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    // prints 'Starting jarx' like expected
  });

  process.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
  });

  process.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    // Not called unless all the spawned java processes are dead :(
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I a have feeling that my problem is related to the child processes sharing `stdio` with the node parent. Indeed where would the `java` processes write if they didn't have a `stdout` to write to. Thus node has to wait for them to be done to consider `starter.sh` done

I have settled for giving the child process it's own `stdio` and write `starter.sh` output to a file:

```
  const out = fs.openSync('/tmp/command.out', 'w');
  const err = fs.openSync('/tmp/command.err', 'w');

  const process = spawn(command, args, {detached: true, stdio: ['ignore', out , err]});
  process.unref();

  process.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    console.log(fs.readFileSync('/tmp/command.out', 'utf8');
    console.log(fs.readFileSync('/tmp/command.err', 'utf8'));
  });
```

That way the `close` call back is called as soon as `starter.sh` is done and I can still access it's output.